# Modify Spring Security Config at Runtime

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am using the latest Spring Boot + Spring Boot Starter Security for a simple proxy application.  The goal is to launch the application with a single route/method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/register",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> register(Registration registration) {
```

With a security configuration of:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    this.http = http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.ADMIN)
    .and();
}

public HttpSecurity getHttpSecurity() {
    return http;
}
```

The goal of the application would be to accept registration requests of the form:

```
{
    "route":"/api/foo/bar",
    "proxy_location": "http://back-end-server/path/to/resource",
    "role": "some-authority"
}
```

And then the application would add an `/api/foo/bar` route with a pre-defined method that will proxy (forward) future requests to the backend service.

I know this is a little goofy, the real use-case involves websockets and dynamic creation of topics.

**The issue I'm facing is that I cannot seem to update the security configuration after the SecurityConfigurer has completed.**

In the code sample above I am caching the `HttpSecurity` object given to my `SecurityConfigurer` and then trying to use that object again to configure a new route:

```
@Inject
private SecurityConfigurer security;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/register",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> allowGetAccounts(Registration registration) {
    try {
        security.getHttpSecurity()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(registration.getRoute()).hasAuthority(registration.getRole());

        ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Updating security failed!", e);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there any way to update the security configuration dynamically during runtime?

Also, if anyone has any notes on creating websocket topics dynamically that would be appreciated too!

Comment: The end goal is to add a role to the user's authority list, correct?

Comment: The end goal is to add a route to the security configuration, basically open an other path for users with a defined role.

Comment: Are you actually getting an exception, or you simply don't see any changes in security applied?

Comment: No exception, I don't see the changes getting applied

Comment: You might rather want to take a look at adding it via HttpSecurity.addFilter, and look at performBuild... don't know what else to offer.  it is a bit unorthodox.  Good luck, I'm looking forward to seeing if you find a solution :)

Comment: is there any solution for updating `spring security config` at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options:

- use `antchMatcher("/some/path").access("@someBean.hasAccess(authentication)")` . This allows you basically use any bean in your application context to apply the validation you need.
- Use `@PreAuthorize("@someBean.hasAccess(authentication)")` on you `RequestMapping` annotated method. Same idea as before but as an interceptor on the endpoint itself.
- Implement your own `SecurityExpressionHandler` and plug it into `http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(...)`.
- Implement your own Security filter that handles whatever you need.