# how to refresh Reactive Spring Security Application on the fly

Tags: spring-security, reactive-programming

I want to refresh my Reactive Spring Security Application on the fly. I have application.yml file which gets some information and use them in a bean with the annotation @EnableWebFlux. The problem is when I want to change something at application.yml file the spring security also be updated without restarting the server.

Do you have any solution for that ?

Do you think there is way to refresh spring security on the fly without restarting the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify Spring Security Config at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089494/modify-spring-security-config-at-runtime)

Comment: no it's not. it's not giving the exact answer that I want.i already checked that before : (

Comment: I think we need more details. What information are you trying to refresh? Rather than using the environment which is scoped to the JVMs lifetime could you create an object that reads from disk the values you need? You could also consider using Spring Cloud's Refresh Scope https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope